# Algorithm to vary coloring in plot series

Tags: graph, colors, plot, flot

I'm trying to get a multi-series plot to display with an even variance of color per plot.  I'm currently thinking something like

```
Plot |  R  |  G  |  B
----------------------
   0 |   0 |   0 |   0
   1 | 255 |   0 |   0
   2 |   0 | 255 |   0
   3 |   0 |   0 | 255
   4 | 128 | 128 |   0
   5 | 128 |   0 | 128
   6 |   0 | 128 | 128
   7 | 170 |  85 |   0
   8 |  85 | 170 |   0
   9 | 170 |   0 |  85
```

Is there already a well-established method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well studied problem that unfortunately doesn't have a good answer.  Presenting data is as much an artform as a science.  Your approach, while yielding decent variance, falls short in two areas:

1. Equally weighting colors and series - your algorithm will produce both bold and muted colors.  The series receiving the bold colors will stand out and dominant the muted series.  They will appear more visually important even if they are not.
2. Aesthetics, aesthetics, aesthetics - many of your colors will end up unpleasant to the eye.  Here's your first 9 for instance:

[image]

So, how do we pick distinctive visually appealing colors?  The first question to ask is how many colors do you really need.  If you only really need nine, I would instead work with a tool like [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) or [iWantHue](http://tools.medialab.sciences-po.fr/iwanthue/) and hardcode one of their palettes.  If you need forty distinct colors, the task is probably impossible.

From the master of data visualization Edward Tufte:

> The often scant benefits derived from  coloring data indicate that
>   even putting a  good color in a good place is a complex  matter.
>   Indeed, so difficult and subtle  that avoiding catastrophe becomes the
>   first principle in bringing color to  information: Above all, do no
>   harm.